# Invoke a method in the object with different types but with a common method

Tags: c#, events

I have a method in a static class that is provided a reference to an eventHandler so that it can keep track of the number of subscribers in it. There can be a number of eventshandlers but all of them have  'GetInvocationList()' method. So, how can I call 'GetInvocationList()' method on objects of different types.

```
static class EventTracker
{
    public static ArrayList arrayList1;

    static EventTracker()
    {
        arrayList1 = new ArrayList();

    }
    public static void AddRecord(String publisherName, object publisher)
    {
        arrayList.Add((publisher as publisherName).GetInvocationList().Length); //doesnot work
    }
}
```

These are the calling methods.

```
EventTracker.AddRecord("SelectionAwareEventHandler", SelectionChanged);
EventTracker.AddRecord("NumberChangedEventHandler", NumberChanged);
```

Here is how event handlers are defined

```
public event SelectionAwareEventHandler SelectionChanged;
public event NumberChangedEventHandler NumberChanged;
```

Comment: What do you mean with a "legacy" project? This is c#. Even the beta version of C# v1.0 supported interfaces.

Comment: I think your code is not complete. The like: `publisher as publisherName` will probably not compile. `publisherName` must be a type, since it follows `as`, but since a string cannot be inherited, this cannot work.

Comment: Yah it does not work. But, I want to call a method like that. I have removed the legacy part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have an untyped event handler reference like

```
object publisher = ...;
MethodInfo getInvocationListMethod = publisher.GetType().GetMethod("GetInvocationList");

// call the method
Delegate[] invocationList = (Delegate[])getInvocationListMethod.Invoke(publisher, null);

int length = invocationList.Length;
```

You could also rewrite your `AddRecord` method to not use `object` but `delegate` for `publisher`. Also `publisher as publisherName` will not compile. And if your `object publisher` is an `EventHandler` e.g. a `delegate` you don´t need the publisher name at all because `GetInvocationList` is defined for all `EventHandler`

```
public static void AddRecord(delegate publisher)
{
    arrayList.Add(publisher.GetInvocationList().Length);
}
```

or simply cast your `publisher` to `delegate` if you are sure `object publisher` will always be a `delegate`

```
public static void AddRecord(object publisher)
{
    arrayList.Add((publisher as Delegate).GetInvocationList().Length);
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer. But is it Delegate or delegate in the last part?

Comment: Yes you are right. We want the type here so it must be ```Delegate```